# Populate parameters to FedEx.com

Tags: http, fedex

I'm trying to populate data to the FedEx.com Shipping or Lite version. 
https://www.fedex.com/lite/lite-ship.html?#address

Is any simple method to pass arguments to that webpage?

Something like: 
https://www.fedex.com/lite/lite-ship.html?#address&to-address=Washington&Zip-code=01234

This will save a lot of copy/paste work.

I'm looking for a very simple solution not a full integration using FedEx Web Services.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want to fill the textboxes from that page? I'm sorry but this just won't work.

The only thing you could try is to create the form by yourself and send it to the server by yourself. But I think would probably need some time to look up the name of the input fields just to then realize that some CORS policy or another security issue would block your request.